# Pass a temporarily modified vector to a function

Tags: c++, vector

In a backtracking problem, I am required to pass a vector to a function in such a way that the vector is modified at each level:

```
void function(std::vector <int> vec){
    vec.push_back(0); // Initial modification
    function(vec);

    vec.pop_back(); // Return to previous state

    vec.push_back(1); // Second modification
    function(vec);

    return;
}
```

I've omitted extraneous code.

Is there any way to simplify the vector modification so that I don't have to pop_back afterwards?

Comment: Modify the vector via operator[]?

Comment: Do you want each call to copy the entire vector?

Comment: @Yakk I've switched to a pass by reference, I had by value because memory handling isn't a problem at the recursion levels the problem dictates, I read somewhere that passing by value can be quicker because of compiler optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that what you have is already fairly readable. There's only two points I would improve on.

First and foremost, pass the vector by reference, avoid the redundant copies.

Secondly, and to maintain the backtracking invariant, you'll still need to maintain the `pop_back`. But you can move it to a less awkward place:

```
void function(std::vector<int> &vec){
    vec.push_back(0); // Initial modification
    function(vec);
    vec.back() = 1;   // Second modification
    function(vec);
    vec.pop_back();   // Return to previous state
    return;
}
```

Because the function pops out the very integer it pushed, we may be certain that `vec.back()` is that integer between calls. So you can do simple assignment instead of another pair of pop and push.

Comment: Well if you want to push and pop each time to the same vector, it's better to use a reference as function argument or define the vector variable globally. Because in this way, you waste a lot of memory.

Comment: This answer is not exception safe, except as far as the pop back is pointless.

Comment: @Yakk - Depends on what throws. If it's only the vector, then a RAII popper is a helmet on a kamikaze.

Comment: @StoryTeller Why wouldn't `function` call throw in its omitted details?

Comment: @Yakk - Because for an assignment in backtracking, it's highly unlikely. I could be wrong of course, but I have strong hunch the OP didn't hide any throwing code from us. Sides, even if they did. I don't see the point in over engineering a RAII popper. The problem can't be solved (or we wouldn't be throwing), so the vector should just be cleaned up when it's scope is unwound. No need to start popping as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a *guard* class that calls `pop_back` automatically for you on destruction:

```
template <typename T>
class push_pop_guard
{
private:
    std::vector<T>& _v;

public:
    template <typename Item>
    push_pop_guard(std::vector<T>& v, Item&& x) : _v{v} 
    { 
        _v.push_back(std::forward<Item>(x));
    }

    ~push_pop_guard()
    {
        _v.pop_back();
    }
};
```

Usage example:

```
void function(std::vector <int> vec)
{
    {
        push_pop_guard ppg{vec, 0};
        function(vec);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: While (very) cool, this adds unnecessary complexity to something simple.

Comment: I would drop T and add C for container.  I'd write a factory function so C can be deduced, and store it as `auto`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the value to the method and push it to vector later:

```
void function(std::vector <int> vec, int element){
    vec.push_back(element);
    //Do stuff
    function(vec,0);
    function(vec,1);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! You might want to make the prototype take `int element = 0` for a default value.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class F>
struct scope_guard_t {
  std::optional<F> f;
  scope_guard_t( F in ):f(std::move(f)) {}
  scope_guard_t( scope_guard_t&& o ):
    f(std::move(o.f))
  {
    o.clear();
  }
  void abandon() { clear(); }
  void commit_early() { commit(); clear(); }
  ~scope_guard_t() { commit(); }
private:
  void commit() { if(f) (*f)(); }
  void clear() { f = std::nullopt; }
};
template<class F>
scope_guard_t<F> scope_guard( F in ) { return {std::move(in)}; }

template<class C, class T>
auto temp_push( C& c, T&& t ) {
  c.push_back( std::forward<T>(t) ); // do
  return scope_guard(
    [&]{ c.pop_back(); } // undo
  );
}
void function(std::vector <int> vec){
  {
    auto scope = temp_push( vec, 0 );
    function(vec);
  }

  {
    auto scope = temp_push( vec, 1 );
    function(vec);
  }
}
```

`std::optional` can be replaced with `boost::optional` in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) and before.

`scope_guard` is generally useful.

I'd also replace the `vector` being passed by value by passing by reference; that can be much more efficient, as it avoids reallocating it for each recursion.